# How to build expo project for IOS app dependent on Firebase Cloud Messaging for push notifications

Tags: react-native, push-notification, expo, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-fcm

I am trying to build my expo project for IOS using EAS build and constantly run into an issue. The project implements:

- "expo": "~48.0.18"
- "react-native": "0.71.8"
  and these firebase modules,
- @react-native-firebase/app": "^18.3.0
- @react-native-firebase/messaging": "^18.3.0,
  which are needed for push notifications, and the required native linking via plugins are properly in place. This works perfectly fine for Android builds.

[The issue came up at this point of the build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLWjk.png)

[The actual error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8unxV.png)

I came across an article stating it has something to do with adding some lines to the podfile and I really don't know how to go about this using expo, neither am I sure that it would help fix the issue for good. I'd really appreciate ideas on how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

If you followed [the docs](https://rnfirebase.io/#altering-cocoapods-to-use-frameworks) you should add `use_frameworks! :linkage => :static` into your `ios/Podfile`.

Don't forget to also disable flipper by commenting out the `:flipper_configuration` in the `use_react_native` method.

Your Podfile should look something like this

```rb
# ios/Podfile

target 'SidegigMobileFrontend' do
  config = use_native_modules!
  use_frameworks! :linkage => :static
  $RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true

  # ...other stuff...
end
```

Comment: Sir, thank you very much. I am most grateful 
I was able to get past that error but got another, stating: Build failed
 spawn pod ENOENT

Comment: It eventually went past that stage after retrying. Muchas gracias senor